# XAP Files not being recognised

Tags: windows-store-apps, package

Hi when i am trying to open .xap files in visual studio 2013, it says no editor is present and it could not find any application that opens the xap file. what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

They are actually Zipped files. Just change the extension to zip and you can view the files

Comment: But how do i convert a xap file to a zip file?

Comment: Just change the .zap extension to .zip and it will extract the files inside the zipped file. There will probably be 5-6 files inside of it.... but as Kristina said, they might be encrypted

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open xap files downloaded from the store you will not be able to read the contents, even if you rename the extension to zip, because they are encrypted.

If this a non-encrypted xap, go to explorer->view and check the File name extensions box, then you will be able to rename the file from xap to zip and browse the contents.